# Why is the application of a Quantum Fourier Transform constant time?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-fourier-transform

I am just curious (complexity theory wise) why the unitary matrix for the QFT (Quantum Fourier Transform) is constant time. From what I know, there is no general way to represent it as a sequence of tensor products of different matrices (for arbitrarily large cases); so how can it be implemented, in sub-polynomial time, on a quantum computer?

For a concrete perspective, imagine a world in which we have quantum computers embedded into our office computers that run the QFT. Say we would like to run it with 500 qubits; how would we compute such a 500 qubit QFT matrix in polynomial time?

I know that it follows a regular pattern when written in matrix form:

$$
F = \begin{bmatrix}
\omega_N^{0 \times 0} & \omega_N^{0 \times 1} & \cdots \\
\omega_N^{1 \times 0} & \omega_N^{1 \times 1} \\
\vdots & & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But how is this really *computed* for arbitrary numbers of qubits in complexity-theory.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1999/55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've heard about the quantum fourier transform without also seeing the circuit for it, but the [wikipedia article on quantum fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform) includes a simple quantum fourier transform circuit with polynomial gate count:

> [image]

The title of your question suggests you're looking for a constant depth circuit, but I'm not aware of any constant depth circuit for the QFT. There are [log depth circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0006004), though.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Høyer and Špalek [proved that](http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2005.v001a005) we can approximate the QFT in constant depth with polynomially small error by using unbounded fanout gates.